# LoadError: no such file to load -- htmlentities

Tags: ruby, rubygems, html-entities

I'm scripting with Ruby 1.8.7 but I get some issues when try to parse html entities with the library "htmlentities".

I cannot load the library although I have installed it withthe gem.Here is the error :

```
1.8.7 :001 > require 'htmlentities'
LoadError: no such file to load -- htmlentities
```

This is my gemlist:

```
actionmailer (2.3.4)
actionpack (2.3.4)
activerecord (2.3.4)
activeresource (2.3.4)
activesupport (2.3.4)
bundler (1.2.0)
htmlentities (4.3.1)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.4)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
```

Comment: The Script works for Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: gem env return this when i make ruby 1.8.7 as default : /home/user/.rvm/bin/gem: line 6: /home/user/.rvm/bin/gem: Argument list too long
/home/user/.rvm/bin/gem: line 6: /home/user/.rvm/bin/gem: Success
else   RubyGems Environment:
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [i686-linux]
INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin
RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
ruby
x86-linux

Comment: You are still pointing to 1.9.2.  Do `rvm use 1.8.7; gem env`

Comment: user@user-ThinkCentre-M58e:~$ rvm use 1.8.7
Using /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358
user@user-ThinkCentre-M58e:~$ gem env
/home/user/.rvm/bin/gem: line 6: /home/user/.rvm/bin/gem: Argument list too long
/home/user/.rvm/bin/gem: line 6: /home/user/.rvm/bin/gem: Success
user@user-ThinkCentre-M58e:~$

Answer (score 5):

Does:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'htmlentities'
```

work?

EDIT: Just noticed you have bundler in the mix. How are you creating the REPL? Are you using a rails console? If so maybe you need to add htmlentities to your Gemfile